# Java casting error: unexpected type. required: variable, found: value

Tags: java, casting

In Java, I am trying to cast an int into a double and then back an int.

I am getting this error:

```
unexpected type
          (double)(result) =  Math.pow((double)(operand1),(double)(operand2));
          ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
```

From this code:

```
(double)(result) =  Math.pow((double)(operand1),(double)(operand2));
return (int)(result);
```

What does the error message mean?

Comment: ...if `result` is an `int`, why not just cast the `pow` result to `int`?

Comment: I tried that and it says the same thing unexpected type

Comment: The problem that causes the error is that you're casting on the left-hand side of an assignment operation.  The cast needs to be immediately to the right of the equals sign, and either double or Double result on the left.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to cast int to double in order to call Math.pow:

```
package test;

public class CastingTest {
    public static int exponent(int base, int power){
        return ((Double)Math.pow(base,power)).intValue();
    }
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        System.out.println(exponent(5,3));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, I'm interested in knowing what the difference would be to casting the result from `Math.pow` to an `int` (using `(int)Math.pow`) and your approach...

Comment: As it turns out, absolutely nothing. :)  
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Double.java#Double.intValue%28%29

Comment: Hmm, interesting none-the-less

Answer (score 1):

The message just means that you've messed up the syntax.  The casting needs to go on the right hand side of the equals, not in front of the variable that you're assigning to.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that `result` is actually a `double`, then you would simply only need to do...

```
result = Math.pow((double)(operand1),(double)(operand2));
```

Now, let's assume that `result` is actually `int`, then you simple need to do...

```
result = (int)Math.pow((double)(operand1),(double)(operand2));
```

**Updated**

With feedback from Patricia Shanahan, there is a lot of unnecessary noise in the code.  Without further context, it is difficult to comment entirely, but, it is unlikely (and unhelpful) to case `operand1` and `operand2` explicitly to `double`.  Java is capable of taking care of this by itself.

```
Math.pow(operand1, operand2);
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, and only downvote with an explanatory comment. However, I disagree with the explicit casts to double on the Math.pow arguments.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That's the OP's code, but that's no excuse.  Without knowing what `operand1` and `operand2`, it's difficult to comment.  I will add an additional comment

Comment: If double could be the target of a [narrowing primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#25363), there would be operand types for which [casting conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.5) would work, but [method invocation conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.3) would not. There are no narrowing primitive conversions the produce a double, so there is no type for operand1 or operand2 for which the cast is both permitted and needed.

Answer (score 0):

This code in Java:

```
double my_double = 5;
(double)(result) = my_double;
```

Will throw an compile time error:

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
```

Casts are not allowed on a variable to the left of the equals sign being assigned to.  It doesn't even make sense what the code would mean.  Are you trying to remind the compiler that your variable is a double?  As if it didn't already know?

Answer (score 0):

you probably intend:

```
double result =  Math.pow((double)(operand1),(double)(operand2));
return (int)(result);
```

or equivalently but more simply:

```
double result =  Math.pow((double)operand1,(double)operand2);
return (int)result;
```

or even:

```
return (int)Math.pow((double)operand1,(double)operand2);
```